# path traversal attacks in rails 4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, brakeman

I am getting `file access` warning for following code:

```
FileUtils.rm(File.join(Project.with_deleted.find_by(
  :user_id => (User.find_by(:username => (params[:user_id])).id),
  :name => (params[:id])
).satellitedir, params[:image_name]))
```

warning is:

> When user-supplied input can contain ".." or similar characters that
>   are passed through to file access APIs, causing access to files
>   outside of an intended subdirectory.

I tried to sanitize params with:

```
 if !params[:image_name].gsub(/\\/, '').index('../')
   #my code
 end
```

but this seem to have no effect on warning of [hakiri](https://hakiri.io/) warning.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of a technique called [tainting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking).

Basically, the `params` object is "tainted" in that it's marked that it comes from user input.

Instead, you need to validate the object and then untaint it yourself. Here's a good article about it: http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/taint.html

Comment: sorry, ircmaxell! I used this: `$SAFE = 1 if params[:image_name] =~ "^[\w\-. ]+$"
      params[:image_name].untaint` but there was no effect on the warning.